# Copy ONLY populated values from one object that are not already populated in another object of the same type

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a requirement to copy ONLY populated values from one object that are not already populated in another object of the same type.

For example we are passed an object, it is only partially instantiated with data, we read the database to get a fully instantiated version of the object – however this may not have changes by the application committed to the database yet – hence we need to move any values from the database version into the passed in version of the object – without overwriting any values that may already exist in the passed in object (as these are the most up to date values).

The code below suggested by Adam Robinson in another post (see below very useful – thanks!) is a good starting point. However I need to extend this – as I only want to copy over values that are NOT already populated on the target object (i.e. need to check the destProperty is not null). However as an added complication, there are internal complex types declared within the object passed in, this code copies the high level sub groups over without going into the individual properties of the sub groups (i.e. any variables declared with the Root cdt I can try and check for null, but all the fields in sub cdts are simply copied over without going through the individual fields).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static void CopyPropertyValues(object source, object destination)
{
    var destProperties = destination.GetType().GetProperties();

foreach (var sourceProperty in source.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    foreach (var destProperty in destProperties)
    {
        if (destProperty.Name == sourceProperty.Name && 
    destProperty.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(sourceProperty.PropertyType))
        {
            destProperty.SetValue(destination, sourceProperty.GetValue(
                source, new object[] { }), new object[] { });

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are the `source` and `destination` of the same class or is it possible that they will differ ? Are they entities in Entity Framework ?

Comment: Source and Destination are of the same class, no they should not differ! Thanks!

Comment: I would filter your properties like this: `.GetProperties().Where(property => property.CanRead && property.CanWrite)`. Otherwise, you might end up trying to read set-only properties or writing to get-only properties.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to determine what *populated* means in your book.
Once you determine that, write you own version of the following `IsDefaultValue` method.
What I have written will answer with `true` in the following manner:

- if it's a `bool` then it needs to have the `false` value
- if it's an `int` then it needs to be `0`
- if it's any `class` then needs to be `null`
- etc

So here's my version of the method:

```
public static bool IsDefaultValue(object @object) {
    if (null == @object)
        return true;
    else if (@object.GetType().IsValueType) {
        var isDefault = Activator.CreateInstance(@object.GetType()).Equals(@object);
        return isDefault;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

Then, presuming that you're interested only in the non indexer properties, that you have no hierarchies and that you will always call this method with objects of the same type,
you could just filter out those properties which are not default in the `source` but are default in the `destination`.

Then you could traverse the instance graph recursively for those cases when you have a non-default value in your destination properties.

Please not that what I have written here is just a demonstration of how you might be able to accomplish your task. There are intricate details in your particular scenario which you need to address yourself as they are not obvious from you question.

For instance, I assumed it would be a good idea to add a stop condition for the recursive traversal (the `remainingDepth` parameter)

```
public static void CopyPropertyValues(object source, object destination, int remainingDepth = 3) {
    // we've reached the farthest point we're allowed to go to
    // anything beyond this point won't be affected by this method
    if (remainingDepth == 0)
        return;
    // just a check to make sure the following lines won't backfire
    if ((null == source) || (null == destination))
        throw new ArgumentNullException();

    // we'll need to also check that the 2 objects are of the same type
    var type = source.GetType();
    if (destination.GetType() != type)
        throw new ArgumentException("The two objects should be of the same type");

    var properties = type.GetProperties()
        // just filter out the properties which are indexers (if any)
        // and also those properties which are read or write only
        .Where(property => (property.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0) &&
                           property.CanRead && property.CanWrite);

    foreach (var property in properties) {
        var sourceValue = property.GetValue(source, null);
        var destValue = property.GetValue(destination, null);

        if (!IsDefaultValue(sourceValue))
            if (IsDefaultValue(destValue))
                property.SetValue(destination, sourceValue, null);
            else
                if (sourceValue.GetType() == destValue.GetType())
                    CopyPropertyValues(sourceValue, destValue, remainingDepth - 1);   
    }

}
```

Please note that property enumeration is needed just once since the objects (as you said it yourself in the comments section) are of the same type.

Also please beware of Reflection when performance is of importance.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to assist, I will experiment with your suggestions!